# how to append a value into the empy text file

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

assume I have an empty text file,

```
touch empty_file
```

How can I insert a specific value into the first line of this empty_file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy. Just use the redirection operator `>` with `echo`:

```
echo 'some value' >empty_file
```

To add a new line after this:

```
echo 'some other value' >>empty_file
```

Comment: if I want to add another value to second line (after inserting first line) why this command don't work; sed -i "2i value" empty_file. How can I add another value to second line?

Comment: @deepblue_86 check my edits

Comment: @jimmij no problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Since this is an empty file, just `echo '<value>' >> file-name`
2. If you want to always insert in the first line, even if file is not empty `sed -i '1s/^/<value>\n/' file-name`

Comment: Note that `\n` in a replacement value only works in GNU `sed`, not BSD `sed`.